# Which statements are true with $\mathcal{F}$ being a fixed nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a fixed nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$ and let $\mathcal{N}^*$ be the ultrapower with domain $\mathbb{N}^{\omega}/ \mathcal{F}$.

The language contains 0,1,+, $\cdot$, < and =.
Which of the following statements are true?

(A) There is an infinitely large number $c$ and a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c^{1/k}=2$

(B) $\mathbb{N}$ is countable

**Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a fixed nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$.**

**Properties**

1. $\mathcal{N}^{\#} \leq_e \mathcal{N}^* $
2. $\mathcal{N} \equiv \mathcal{N}^* $
3. $\mathcal{N} \not \approx \mathcal{N}^* $

I think (A) is correct. And that there is an infinitely large number $c$ and a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $c= 2^k$.

But how should I prove this? Should I do something with the properties?

My proof of why I think (B) is not true:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an ultrafilter on an infinite set $\mathbb{N}$. Then for any subset $X \subseteq S$ precisely one of $X \in\mathcal{F}$ or $X^c \in\mathcal{F}$ holds. So, half of the sets in $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ are in $\mathcal{F}$. Clearly the cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$ is thus the same as the cardinality of $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ , which is uncountable since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Is this correct?

Comment: (B) is about the cardinality of $\mathcal N^*$, right? Your argument is about $|\mathcal F|$ which is correct but irrelevant. How is $c^{1/k}$ defined? Anyhow, wouldn't $c^{1/k}=2$ be equivalent to $c=2^k$?

Comment: Thus since the cardinality of $\mathcal{N}^*$ is uncountable and by property 3 I can say that $\mathcal{N}$ is uncountable?

Comment: I dont understand what your question is for (A)

Comment: 'The language contains $0,1,+,-,\cdot,<$ and $=$.' - it doesn't contain exponential and division. How is then $c^{1/k}=2$ meant? $\Bbb N$ is definitely countable. The ultraproduct $\mathcal N^*$ is uncountable but this is not shown by your argument.

Comment: I should define exponential and division by a wf containing the symbols in the language!

Comment: How do i know that there are countably or uncountable many e.q.classes?